# Magento 2: import product with many other data fields

Tags: magento2, product, import, custom-field

I want to import many products with many custom fields. How can I do that, I hope anyone helps me, Thank in advance.
Here is notice when I import product with many custom field
[image]

Comment: your csv format is not good, which is required from magento, first download csv format than import...

Comment: I just want to import with custom many fields. Do you have any idea?

Comment: first try to create one product with custom fields than export product and than check format, in your attachment have format issue.

Comment: @MichaelHa, please attach the csv file which you are trying to import

Comment: HI @Manjunath https://drive.google.com/file/d/1f9t4REhn8-Ant58zRB6S0yRx1Rh1PctX/view?usp=sharing please check it.

Answer (score 1):

Please use Magmi to import/update product with custom field in Magento 2. Magmi is import product data fast and direct on database. Magmi also create Select box options value automatic.

Please referee sample CSV file for product custom field

```
sku           price  custom_field1
PR-MB01       31       abx
PR-MX02       32       pqr
PR-UG04       94       ty
PR-UG05       100
```

Download from URL:https://github.com/macopedia/magmi-m2/tree/82ae373630c5291fc72ce948935916a811dc4f8b

Make sure if you have php version <7.2 then user below git repository for magmi download https://github.com/macopedia/magmi-m2/tree/82ae373630c5291fc72ce948935916a811dc4f8b

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I don't use it.